# How can I divide a vector containing strings to sub-vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing a program that needs to read data from a text file and put them in a vector. Then I need to divide the vector into sub-vectors. This is an exam of my vector:

```
JOB  1
CORE 50
DISK 10
CORE 150
JOB   2
CORE 50
DISK 10
CORE 150
DISK 0
CORE 100
JOB   3
CORE 50
DISK 10
```

As you can see I have 3 jobs here and need to divide my vector before the next job starts. The new vectors should be as the following:

```
Vector 1:
JOB  1
CORE 50
DISK 10
CORE 150

Vector 2:
JOB   2
CORE 50
DISK 10
CORE 150
DISK 0
CORE 100

Vector 3:
JOB   3
CORE 50
DISK 10
```

So far I have been able to create the first sub-vector but I don't know how to split them from where I should split.

This is how I created the first sub-vector.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < job.size(); i++){
    if(job.at(i) != "JOB" ){
        first_sub_vector_job.push_back(job.at(i));
        first_sub_vector_time.push_back(time.at(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the definitions of the vectors?

Comment: I am writing a job simulator. The first column is job type and the second one is time for that job.

Comment: Vectors don't have columns. How are you expressing columns? How have you defined your vector so that it contains two values (or two columns)?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I have two vectors for those two columns. first_sub_vector_job and first_sub_vector_time. One stored the strings and the other one stored integers. When I said columns I meant the columns on my text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new subvector every time you encounter the string `"JOB"` and always add to the last vector added. It's better to just use a single vector containing objects containing all the info for a single entry instead of storing the string and the number in separate vectors. The code below uses `pair<string, int>` for this purpose.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> input
{
    {"JOB", 1},
    {"CORE", 50},
    {"DISK", 10},
    {"CORE", 150},
    {"JOB", 2},
    {"CORE", 50},
    {"DISK", 10},
    {"CORE", 150},
    {"DISK", 0},
    {"CORE", 100},
    {"JOB", 3},
    {"CORE", 50},
    {"DISK", 10},
};

std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>> result;

auto pos = input.cbegin();
auto end = input.cend();

while (pos != end)
{
    auto& out = result.emplace_back(); // add new vector

    // fill the vector until we encounter the next JOB
    do
    {
        out.push_back(*pos);
        ++pos;
    } while (pos != end && pos->first != "JOB");
}

for (auto& list : result)
{
    std::cout << "----------------------\n";
    for (auto& job : list)
    {
        std::cout << job.first << " " << job.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get an error for the following line: auto& out = result.emplace_back(); // add new vector  . The error is "Cannot form a reference to 'void'"

Comment: @Mah looks like an issue with the vector implementation your compiler uses. You should be able to use `result.push_back(std::move(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>())); auto& out = result.back();` instead though.